# subscription In Sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get subscribe records when I have 2 condition on a field.look at this table.

```
  ╔══════╦══════════╗
  ║ Name ║ FolderID ║
  ╠══════╬══════════╣
  ║ A    ║        3 ║
  ║ A    ║        2 ║
  ║ B    ║        3 ║
  ║ B    ║        2 ║
  ║ C    ║        2 ║
  ╚══════╩══════════╝
```

The result that I want to see: A,B
because C has not FolderId 3.

Comment: Hint: `WHERE` Clause + `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`

Comment: You say you have two conditions. One of them seems to be FolderId 3, but what's the other condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select [Name] from MY_TABLE where FolderID = 2
intersect
select [Name] from MY_TABLE where FolderID = 3
```

Comment: Yea,That is it.Thanks  but I don't know which way is better and fast between your solution and @Vijayakumar

Comment: execuse me I typed incorrect I mean @Yogesh Sharma's Hint in the comment

Comment: Well, show me how you'll do it then I tell which is faster.

Comment: I can group it by name after that compare having count(*) with condition count

Comment: select id from (select * from table where folderid in (2,3)) group by id having count(*)=2

Comment: @MohsenZahedi That's not gonna work :) The solution using these hints I can think of is less eficient than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question.

This will get the results which you are looking for

```
select * from tablename where FolderID=3
```

I hope this will suffice

Comment: No , you couldn't get it.I want Names that their FolderIds eqaul 2 and equal 3 at the same time

Comment: In fact I want subscription between these.

Comment: You can use grouby / in statement plus where condition to get the desired results. 
Query : select * from tablename where FolderID in (2,3) GROUP BY Name

Answer (score 0):

Taking the group by  clause for the column name , count(distinct folderid) > 1 is indicates the only folder id 2 and 3 will be taken

```
select name
from table
group by name
having count(distinct folderid) > 1
```

Comment: Please add some explanations editing your answer, avoid code only answer and take a look to : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer